# how to send a request that contains dom Element in JSON format using jersey REST client

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I have `jersey` `REST` client in my `java` application, I want to send a request in `JSON` format, and the request `object` contains `Element`.

When I send request with `XML` format everything works fine, but when try to send request with `JSON` format server failed to send a request.

If I create `Element` without appending to a `Document` it generate following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle
```

If I create `Element` and append it to a `Document` it generate following error(`doc.appendChild(root);`):

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

this is the way I create my request Object:

```
public OTAAirLowFareSearchRS AirLowFareSearch(OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ request) throws Exception {
        OTAAirLowFareSearchRS response = new OTAAirLowFareSearchRS();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("TPA_Extension");
        doc.appendChild(root); // This the line I mention above that create different errors
        Element e = doc.createElement("CUSTOM_VAR");
        root.appendChild(e);
        e.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("CUSTOM_VALUE"), e.getLastChild());
        TPAExtensionsType tpa = new TPAExtensionsType();
        tpa.getAny().add(root);
        request.getPOS().getSource().get(0).setTPAExtensions(tpa);
        JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig(jacksonJsonProvider));
        WebTarget target = client.target(GlobalVariable.bus_url).path("AirLowFareSearch");
        response = target
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE),
                OTAAirLowFareSearchRS.class);
        return response;
}
```

When I send my request with `XML` format like below everything works:

```
        //JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        //Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig(jacksonJsonProvider));
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(GlobalVariable.bus_url).path("AirLowFareSearch");
        response = target
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE),
                OTAAirLowFareSearchRS.class);
```

When I send my request without adding `Element` I can send `JSON` request too (so there is no error in configuring `JSON`).

Also this is `Open Travel` object and I can't change the request too.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem comes from DOM Elements. the best way to solve it is to use map instead of DOM elements so you can deal with Maps easily.